# Inequality-Lp Spaces(0<p<1)

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $L^p(\Bbb R,\Bbb M,m)$ with $p\in(0,1)$ the space of Lebesgue measurable functions with $$\int_{\Bbb R}|f|^pdm<\infty $$ I want to establish the following inequality: If $f,g \in L^p(\Bbb R, \Bbb M,m)$, then  $$||f+g||_{p}\le2^p(||f||_{p}+||g||_{p}) $$
where $$||f||_{p}=\Bigg(\int_{\Bbb R}|f|^pdm\Bigg)^{1/p}$$
Any advice would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First show that for $p\geq 0$ and real numbers $a$ and $b$

$$|a+b|^p\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).$$ Indeed,

$$
|a+b|\leq |a|+|b|\leq 2\max\{|a|,|b|\}$$
and thus 
$$ |a+b|^p\leq (2\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p=2^p((\max\{|a|,|b|\})^p)\leq 2^p(|a|^p+|b|^p).
$$

That pretty much solves your problem.